# Configuration of USB Hub

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, usb, relay, usb-device

I'm planning to design a USB hub and planned to select this [device](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/USB5744-Data-Sheet-DS00001855J.pdf)

My design questions:

1. From the datasheet, if the SS signals (Tx and Rx signals) for the downstream ports are not used, then it is mentioned that it can be left floating. Can the upstream ports' SS signals (Tx and Rx) be left floating if not used?

Section 4.3 on page 8 of this [checklist](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/USB5744-Hardware-Design-Checklist-00002970A.pdf) mentions, "If a downstream port of the USB5744 is unused, it should be disabled. This can be achieved through hub configuration (I2C or OTP), or through a port disable strap option.
If using the port disable strap option, the USB_DP2 and USB_DM2 signals should be pulled high to 3.3V. This connection can be made directly to the 3.3V power net, or through a pull-up resistor. All other signals related to the associated port may be floated."

Can the USB 2.0 upstream signals be floating too?

2. In this [document](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/an262.pdf), section 3.6.5.1, it mentions that SS Tx and Rx signals need 90 ohms differential signal connection between the host and the hub. But [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401539/usb-3-0-length-matching-in-pcb-layout), the accepted answer states that the SS Tx ad Rx is not required to be 90 Ω impedance matched between the Hub and the Host. Which one is correct?

Just a small clarification in addition to the above.

Suppose I am using a MUX for the downstream ports, whether the USB2.0 signals going into and out of the MUX, should they be 90 Ω?

Comment: There's two unrelated questions, one about how to use a chip, and other about if impedance matching should be used or not. If you connect a USB 3.0 hub to a 2.0 port on a PC, are the SS pins floating or not - does this answer your question? On the other hand, if making a USB 2.0 hub, why use a USB 3.0 chip at all? Why use a mux on a hub downstream port if you have a hub chip and want to disable ports on it so you could work without mux? Also why would impedance matching would not be needed, if it is not needed why would we ever use it to begin with?

Comment: Also the answer you link as saying 90 ohm impedance matching is not needed, actually never says what you claim.

Comment: @Justme, 
"If you connect a USB 3.0 hub to a 2.0 port on a PC, are the SS pins floating or not - does this answer your question?" - I dont understand this

Comment: @Justme, actually in the document, it says the impedance matching is required for SS signals. But the accepted answers says it is not required. Which one to follow?

Comment: the accepted answer, or question, are not about impedance matching.

Comment: @Justme, then could you clarify my actual question?

Comment: You have 4 different questions. I don't know which is the actual question and how to make that question more clear.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between length matching and impedance matching. Impedance matching is required. Length matching for a pair is required. Length matching between pairs is not. The referenced SE question only refers to length matching.

Comment: @Kartman, so the impedance matching is required for the SS signals right? And you are talking about the SS signals only right?

Comment: Section 3.6.5.1 seems pretty explicit. It says what signals are involved. Why would you think there is room for negotiation? How do your conversations with ChatGPT go?